# Python: Parsing and grouping filenames in directory

Tags: python, parsing, directory

I'm pretty new to python, but I have lots of experience with MATLAB & C.

What I need to do it parse the filenames of files in a particular directory, separate them into groups according to the fields within the file names, and perform operations within these groups.

Specifically, the filenames are:

```
PROJECT-x-SUBJECT-x-SESSION-x-TYPE.extension
```

where that '-x-' has been purposely inserted as the field divider. I need to do operations on every group of files that shares the same PROJECT-x-SUBJECT-x-SESSION component.

__*_*____*My best attempt follows:* __*_*__*_*__

I can parse each of the files one at a time by:

```
dirList=os.listdir(directory)
for fname in dirList:  
    # kill extension
    ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    # get the 4 fields 
    labels=ext[0].split('-x-')
    PROJECT_list.append(labels[0])
    SUBJECT_list.append(labels[1])
    ...
```

... which reflects this only idea I have had on how to organize this stuff:  by creating 4 lists and appending to them for each filename.

Then with my 4 (ordered?) lists, I could then call something like:

```
from collections import Counter
c=Counter(SESSION_list) 
list(c)
```

*Then at least I have a unique list of SESSION names*

Suggestions? I could go on, but since I really just need a starting point, I think that this is sufficient.

Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` to make a dictionary that contains lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

groups = defaultdict(list)

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    project, subject, session, ftype = basename.split('-x-')

    groups[session].append(filename)
```

Now, `groups` contains a mapping between session names and filenames.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `defaultdict` to group filenames, `glob` to find the appropriate files, and `fileinput` to read lines from all files with the same key. (untested)

```
import os
from glob import glob
import fileinput
from collections import defaultdict

filenames = glob('*-x-*')
dd = defaultdict(list)
for filename in filenames:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    dd[tuple(name.split('-x-')[:3])].append(filename)

for key, fnames in dd.iteritems():
     for line in fileinput.FileInput(fnames):
         pass # do something with lines from files with same key
```